# How to properly declarate a suspend inline function with reified parameters?

Tags: kotlin, naming-conventions

I haven't found any simular questions and answers, but I don't understand what I should do in a situation like this: there is a function with long declaration and not so long name.

Is there any convention rule saying about breaking a line there? or the only way is to shorten method name?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only improvement I see here is that you add the generic type constraints using `where` at the end (on a new line).
Check out the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints